# T-SQL Pad a nvarchar number with leading character and zeros for a 9 character format A00000012

Tags: sql

How to pad a `nvarchar` number with leading zeros and the first character is alpha. I have to concatenate an `id` to some leading characters to insert some records. The column type is `nvarchar 9`. sql server 2008r

```
A000000012
A000002212
A002322212
```

Comment: so you want to covert 'A1' to A00000001 ?
And 'B001' to 'B00000001' ?

Comment: we have sql server 2008r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a bit of old school left padding for T-SQL:

```
select Id, 'A'+RIGHT(CONCAT(REPLICATE('0',8),Id),8) as PaddedId
from YourTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

If 2012+ you can use **Format()**

```
Select 'A'+format(12,'000000000')
```

Returns

```
A000000012
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the static part you need to pad? If it is `A00`, then:

```
Select 'A00' + CAST(Col_Number as varchar(50)) as 'New_string'
From Table
```

Answer (score 0):

in Oracle:

```
select substr('A123',1,1) || substr('00000000',8-length('A123')) || substr('A123',2)  from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @yourtable TABLE(somenumber int);
INSERT @yourtable VALUES (12), (2212), (2322212);

-- Solution 2012+
SELECT NewValue = CONCAT('A', REPLICATE('0', 9-LEN(somenumber)), somenumber)
FROM @yourtable;

-- Pre-SQL 2012
SELECT NewValue = 'A'+REPLICATE('0', 9-LEN(somenumber))+CAST(somenumber AS nvarchar(9))
FROM @yourtable;
```

Both Return:

```
NewValue   
-----------
A000000012 
A000002212 
A002322212
```